# How do I return the function name of a class method being passed in as an argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, testing

I have a class called `bio_seq` with a class method called `transcribe()` and I am doing an exercise to create my own unit tests. I have created a function called `unitTest()` such as below so I have a wrapper function to perform tests on all of my class methods:

```
def unitTest(func, output):
    try:
        assert func == output
        print(f'{NAMEGOESHERE} Passed')
    except AssertionError:
        print(f'Test Failed for {NAMEGOESHERE}')
```

Running this code would look like the following where `test_dna` is an instantiated `bio_seq` object:

```
unitTest(test_dna.transcribe(), 'AUGC')
```

How do I get the method name of transcribe() in my unitTest() function to be passed into the {NAMEGOESHERE} f blocks?

I have tried using **ne** but this returns `<method-wrapper '__ne__' of bio_seq object at 0x000001CA41F6F2D0>`.

I want the return of the above to be: 'transcribe'

Comment: you **aren't passing a method into `unitTest`**. You are *calling a method* and passing in the *result*. At that point, `unitTest` has **no access to the function**.

Comment: Ahh, of course! Do you see a simple way to pass in this class method to this function or would it just make more sense at a smaller scale to just pass in a sting of the function name as a 3rd argument to `unitTest`? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Either way would be workable

Answer (score 0):

```py
def unitTest(func, output):
    try:
        assert func() == output
        print(f'{func.__name__} Passed')
    except AssertionError:
        print(f'Test Failed for {func.__name__}')

class DNA:
    def transcribe(self):
        return 3

test_dna = DNA()

unitTest(test_dna.transcribe, 3)
unitTest(test_dna.transcribe, 4)
```

Comment: I understand how this would work for a regular function, but I am trying to pass in a class method such as: `obj.foo()`. How would you achieve the same output with this instead?

Comment: @Chephen it's the same thing, I edited to demonstrate.